# Java: how to repeatedly asks the user for Y or N

Tags: java

I am doing a JAVA project for newton iteration, but I am stuck in how to make the program keep asking the user if they want to keep going or not. And also how to make sure when the user entering negative numbers, the result is not showing the root is the negative number that user entered.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
* Computes estimate of square root of x to within relative error 0.01%.
* 
* @param x
*            positive number to compute square root of
* @return estimate of square root
*/

public final class Newton1 {
    private static double sqrt(double x) {
        if (x < 0) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a postive number.");
            return x;
        }
        double Error = 0.0001;
        double t = x;
        while (Math.abs(t - x / t) > Error * t) {
            t = (x / t + t) / 2.0;
        }
        return t;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        double x = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Square root is " + sqrt(x));
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue? (Enter Y or N): ");
        String f = in.nextLine();
        while (true) {
            if (f.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to ask for input in a loop.

Comment: You should try looking up your question before posting on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` statement appears to be in the wrong place. Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter a non-negative number: ");
            double x = in.nextDouble();
        } while (x < 0);
        System.out.println("Square root is " + sqrt(x));
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue? (Enter Y or N): ");
        String f = in.nextLine();
        if (!f.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that until the user enters a non-negative number, they will continue to be prompted for a non-negative number.